# Rendering Problems Android Studio 0.8.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated Android Studio to 0.8.2 and at first I had Gradle problems and Rendering Problems. 
My Rendering Problem was that I didn't select a render target. After fixing this problem I got another Rendering problem.

> Rendering Problems File C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio2\sdk\platforms\android-19\data\layoutlib.jar doesnt exist (Details).

I've searched so much on the internet and I even downloaded the `layoutlib.jar` file but it didn't solve my problem. I really need help because I wanna concentrate on my work.

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. What worked for me is deleting the SDK Platform for the specific API (19 in this case) using Android SDK manager.  If you open SDK manager and expand the different Platforms packages like Android 5.0.1(API 21) and so on, you'll see the respective SDK Platform underneath. Select the one you're having trouble with and delete it. Then reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update SDK.

Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager, when the manager is opened packages which have updates will be checked, you just click "Install packages".

Answer (score 1):

Delete all items in andoid 21 and install again. Your problem will be solved. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Just **uninstall and reinstall**

> specific android APK

with android here it **android-19**

Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager

> 1.uncheck the ***specific android APK*** android check box the apply (wait if need to unistall)
>
> 2. recheck the same ***specific android APK*** android apk and then click on Apply